# Mysql Connection error on a new Phoenix 1.4 project

Tags: mysql, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to setup a brand new phoenix 1.4 project with mysql on a macbook pro and I ran into this error on `mix ecto.create`

```
> mix phx.new vernal --database mysql
```

(I then set the root username and password on config/dev.exs)

```
> mix ecto.create

15:05:33.863 [error] GenServer #PID<0.223.0> terminating
** (RuntimeError) connect raised FunctionClauseError exception.The exception details are hidden, as they may contain sensitive data such as database credentials. You may set :show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error to true if you wish to see all of the details
    (mariaex) lib/mariaex/protocol.ex:1092: Mariaex.Protocol.password/3
    (mariaex) lib/mariaex/protocol.ex:212: Mariaex.Protocol.handle_handshake/3
    (mariaex) lib/mariaex/protocol.ex:171: Mariaex.Protocol.handshake_recv/2
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:66: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Mariaex.Protocol
** (Mix) The database for Vernal.Repo couldn't be created: %RuntimeError{message: "killed"}
```

My environment:

macOS Sierra (version 10.12.6)

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.11 for macos10.13 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

Using the same root username and password I can successfully up mysql in the terminal just fine, MySQL Workbench also works fine, it shows it's running on port 3306, and I can make and execute queries so I believe MySQL should be installed correctly.

```
iex --version
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.2.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]

IEx 1.8.0 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 21)

mix phx.new --version
Phoenix v1.4.0

mix.lock has "mariaex": "0.9.1"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly related to https://github.com/xerions/mariaex/issues/222

Comment: downgraded to mysql 5.7 instead of using 8.0 and it works

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still checking?

> https://github.com/elixir-ecto/myxql

is the package that works for the MySQL V8

```
def deps() do
 [
   {:myxql, "~> 0.4.0"}
 ]
end
```